# TV flickers when AC shuts down

Tags: electrical

My 220 AC is somehow causing tv to flicker when the ac shuts down.  The ac and tv are not on same circuit.  Replaced the tv but replacement does same thing.  Could the ac shutting down cause a voltage surge in the circuit which feeds the tv and cause the flickering and momentarily shut down?  If so would surge protector eliminate problem?

Comment: I think you'd need a "power conditioner" and not just a simple surge protector. But, do your lights dim when the AC shuts off? IME, that would be from a poor neutral connection (likely at the incoming pole).

Comment: Is it the TV power, or the cable/satellite signal that flickers?

Answer (score 1):

A UPS would be the only way to totally fix the problem condoning and surge protection only filter very short time based spikes, but do not do much more than that. A UPS constantly supplies power to the device through a inverter. When there is a problem they use battery power to supply the inverter until the battery is depleted.

Comment: A power conditioner may or may not be cheaper than a full UPS; it *should* be a bit less expensive, but the wider marketing of UPS units may make them more widely stocked and less expensive at retail.

Comment: @RonDean Surge protectors are typically designed to absorb a limited number of surges, after that they no longer offer protection.

Comment: Uninterrupted power supplies (UPS) require battery replacement, which is an added expense that needs to be factored in. In my experience, the batteries don't tend to last too long (1-2 years), especially in lower priced units.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right about "the only way" to fix the problem. It is certainly a very good, cost effective solution, but is it the only solution? Is there a broader option to fix the root cause?

Comment: Regarding cost - Consider what the voltage spikes or drops are doing to the TV. An inexpensive UPS every few years or replacement batteries protect much more expensive TVs, stereos, gaming systems, routers, etc etc.